# A relatively new tire question

Tags: tires

I have 3,300 miles on my car.  I went to have the tires rotated and they said I have a small bubble on the driver side front. Can the tire be repaired? If I buy the exact same tire will the car drive the same?  It is only 8 months old.

Comment: No, the tire cannot be repaired.

Comment: I will definitely not buy the same brand again. Bubbles tend to burst and cause accidents.

Answer (score 4):

If there is a defect in the tire, there is a tire manufacturers warranty which applies. You should not have to pay to have it replaced. As long as you don't have appreciable wear on (which 3300 miles should not create), you should be just fine with a new replacement. The car should drive just the same with a new replacement.